# DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity]

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

I want to cache the List in redis. Below is the service method for the same:-

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

@Cacheable(value = "notes", key = "#userId")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllNotes(Integer userId) {

        HashOperations<String, String, Object> hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
        //Check if the cacheKey contains this userId
        if (hashOperations.hasKey(cacheKey, userIdAsKey)) {
            List<NoteResponse> noteResponses = (List<NoteResponse>) hashOperations.get(cacheKey, userIdAsKey);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(noteResponses);
        }

        List<Note> notes = noteRepository.findAllByUserId(userId);
        List<NoteResponse> noteResponses = Helper.getNoteResponse(notes);
        hashOperations.put(cacheKey, userIdAsKey, noteResponses);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(noteResponses);
}
```

but i am getting this exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity]

Comment: related?: https://github.com/hendisantika/spring-data-redis-sample

Answer (score 2):

Add **implements Serializable** to the end of the NoteResponse for example

public class NoteResponse implements Serializable