Spring Boot Redis Cache DefaultSeriaLizer Problem
I'm trying to implement Redis caching in my Spring Boot project to cache user profile information retrieved by the getProfileByUsername method in the UserService class. However, encountering a Serialization Exception when attempting to cache the retrieved UserDto object.
Error Message:
2024-07-18T10:54:15.540+06:00 ERROR 22776 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [com.rokomari.meal_Management_System.dto.response.UserDto]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer.serializeToByteArray(Serializer.java:56) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:33) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:92) ~[spring-data-redis-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.DefaultRedisElementWriter.write(DefaultRedisElementWriter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext$SerializationPair.write(RedisSerializationContext.java:292) ~[spring-data-redis-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.serializeCacheValue(RedisCache.java:368) ~[spring-data-redis-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.put(RedisCache.java:226) ~[spring-data-redis-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.performCachePut(CacheAspectSupport.java:1031) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:1016) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.evaluate(CacheAspectSupport.java:560) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:433) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:395) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:74) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at com.rokomari.meal_Management_System.services.UserService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getProfileByUsername(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.rokomari.meal_Management_System.controllers.UserController.getProfile(UserController.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:188) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.rokomari.meal_Management_System.filter.JwtFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtFilter.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.25.jar:10.1.25]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]



User Service Code => :
 @Cacheable(value = "UserInfo", key = "#username")
    public UserDto getProfileByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElse(null);
        return modelMapper.map(user, UserDto.class);
    }

I want to add redis-cache in my spring boot project. but it didn't work

seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258699/defaultserializer-requires-a-serializable-payload-but-received-an-object-of-type

This question is similar to: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity]. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
